# calculate fps of html5 canvas game with javascript

Tags: javascript, runtime, frame-rate, requestanimationframe

I am creating a html5 canvas game and want to check how many frames pass in one second. I have tried using new Date(), and it is not working. How would I manage to do this?
javascript template/example:

```
var fps;
function loop(){
    //some code

    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
function checkFrameRate(){
    fps = //how long it takes for loop to run
    window.requestAnimationFrame(checkFrameRate);
}
loop();
checkFrameRate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop function check the time passed between executions.

```
let lastTime = new Date();
function loop() { 
    const currentTime = new Date();
    // currentTime - lastTime is the number of milliseconds passed from last loop 
    const fps = 1000 / (currentTime - lastTime);
    lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `performance.now()` instead of `new Date()`:

```js
let fps;
let requestTime;

function loop(time) {
    if (requestTime) {
        fps = Math.round(1000/((performance.now() - requestTime)));
    }

    console.log(fps);
    requestTime = time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame((timeRes) => loop(timeRes));
}

window.requestAnimationFrame((timeRes) => loop(timeRes));
```